# Find a node and it's matching descendant node in one query

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml that I need to get 2 values (see * in comments) from within the same query:
The two values are associated and I can get one set (`) or the other () but not using a single query.`

**Update** I updated the xml below to include 2 nodes that exist under the  node and added the namespace

Ideally I would like to get them both in a single query into a Dictionary

```
<root xmlns="http://www.blah.net/xsd/layout/2003-10-16">
    <header/>
    <movement>
        <movementHeader>
            <desc>xyz</desc>
        </movementHeader>
        <detailHeader>
            <desc>abc</desc>
        </detailHeader>
        <detail>
            <!-- * need this value -->
            <code>90125</code>
            <subDetail>
                <!-- * and need this value at same time -->
                <amount>1200.00</amount>
            </subDetail>
        </detail>
        <detail>
            <!-- * need this value -->
            <code>90126</code>
            <subDetail>
                <!-- * and need this value at same time -->
                <amount>1300.00</amount>
            </subDetail>
        </detail>
        <detail>
            <!-- * need this value -->
            <code>9012</code>
            <subDetail>
                <!-- * and need this value at same time -->
                <amount>1400.00</amount>
            </subDetail>
        </detail>
    </movement>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can project to an anonymous type that holds the properties you want:

```
var results = xdoc.Descendants("detail")
                  .Select( x => new 
                   {
                       Code = x.Element("code").Value,
                       Amount = x.Element("subDetail")
                                 .Element("amount").Value 
                   });

foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Code = {0}, Amount = {1}", item.Code, item.Amount);
}
```

Tested and works, returns 3 results as expected.

To add this to a dictionary just add `ToDictionary()` :

```
var dict = xdoc.Descendants("detail")
               .Select(x => new
                {
                   Code = x.Element("code").Value,
                   Amount = x.Element("subDetail")
                             .Element("amount").Value
                }).ToDictionary(x => x.Code, x => x.Amount);
```

**Edit:**

To account for the XML namespace you have to declare and use it, updated example below:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.blah.net/xsd/layout/2003-10-16";
var dict = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "detail")
               .Select(x => new
               {
                  Code = x.Element(ns + "code").Value,
                  Amount = x.Element(ns + "subDetail")
                            .Element(ns + "amount").Value
               }).ToDictionary(x => x.Code, x => x.Amount);
```

Comment: Tried your solution and it yielded no results. The xml is a little more complicated (updated above) in that it has odd nodes added to the <movement> node and it has a namespace.  I suspect the NS is an issue and added XNamespace to your code sample but still not returning results

Comment: @Tab: use `Element((XNamespace)nsString + "tagname")`

Comment: I tried this before I posted a comment on your answer:

XNamespace nsr = Settings.DefaultNamespace;
...
Element(nsr + "Code").Value,

Comment: Awesome!  Works perfect - thanks!  I was so wrapped up in specifics that I did not see this - great solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = from d in doc.Root.Element("movement").Elements("detail")
        let amount = (string)d.Element("subDetail").Element("amount")
        select new 
        {
            Code = (string)d.Element("code"),
            Amount = Decimal.Parse(amount)
        };
```

Comment: Since the whole sample you gave is processed as a single statement it is hard to discern which 'line'

Comment: @Tab: You can separate each LINQ call to a separate variable. That will point what call does use nulled reference thus causes the exception.

Comment: I understand that. Thanks for the help.  I think I have moved on.